# Sorting at the time of indexing using using lucene 4.0

Tags: java, lucene

Is it possible to sort the documents at the time of indexing only using lucene 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort Lucene index when you search in index.

This link may help you [Older Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993275/store-documents-based-on-sort-order-in-lucene-index)

You may see this link when you [change from Lucene 3 to 4](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/171163)
and [this] for older version.[3](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html)